# How to resolve login issue in the snowSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just installed SnowSQL on windows OS. but getting error while login with default username and password in snowFlake

```
PS C:\> snowsql -a sfc-repo -u username
Password:
```

> 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com:443. HTTP 403: Forbidden
> If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
> Goodbye!

Comment: The user name and password are wrong.  Have you reached out to support?

Answer (score 1):

The "sfc-repo" is supposed to be your Snowflake account name.  The documentation below has some examples:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html